# Selected item not showing in a WPF combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm creating a part of my window in code.  For a combobox I do this:

```
ObservableCollection<ParamClassOption> options = new ObservableCollection<ParamClassOption>(
context.ParamClassOptions.Where(x => x.IDParamClass == val.CompTypeParam.IDParamClass));

ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox();
combobox.Name = "combobox" + val.CompTypeParam.ParameterName.Replace(" ", "");
combobox.ItemsSource = options;
combobox.SelectedValuePath = "IDParamClass";
combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "OptionName";
if (val.ParamClassOption != null)
{ 
  combobox.SelectedValue = val.ParamClassOption.IDParamClassOption; 
}
layoutitem.Content = combobox;
```

I'm able to select an item from the list and save it to the database.  The problem that I have is to show the saved value again upon retrieving the values back from the database.  Any idea why it's not showing?  val.ParamClassOption.IDParamClassOption in the second to last line above has the correct value when the record is retrieved to be displayed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help.  I ended up using a completely different approach by adding the items to the combo-box one by one.  I then set the selected item to previously added value (using the Text property).  Here is what my code looks like now:

```
            if (controlType == "Combobox")
            {
                ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox();
                combobox.Name = "combobox" + val.CompTypeParam.ParameterName.Replace(" ", "");

                ObservableCollection<ParamClassOption> options = new ObservableCollection<ParamClassOption>(
                    context.ParamClassOptions.Where(x => x.IDParamClass == val.CompTypeParam.IDParamClass));
                combobox.Items.Clear(); 
                foreach (ParamClassOption option in options)
                {
                    ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
                    item.Content = option.OptionName;
                    combobox.Items.Add(item);
                }
                combobox.Text = val.ParamClassOption.OptionName;

                layoutitem.Content = combobox;
            }
```

Later when reading the value from the combobox to save to the database I did this:

```
ObservableCollection<ParamClassOption> option = new ObservableCollection<ParamClassOption>(
    context.ParamClassOptions.Where(o => o.IDParamClass == value.CompTypeParam.IDParamClass).Where(o => o.OptionName == combobox.Text));
value.IDParamClassOption = option[0].IDParamClassOption;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to bind your selected value

```
var binding = new Binding {Path = new PropertyPath("IDParamClassOption"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = val.ParamClassOption};
combobox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, binding);
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't work.  This is the error I get when I select one of the options from the combobox:

    The property 'IDParamClassOption' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Just one thing, my combobox's datacontext isn't set.  I'm  just getting the records and create a control for each record.  Controls can be a TextBox, Combobox, Checkbox etc.  That's the reason for not using a datacontext

Comment: @Amanda You can use an `ObservableCollection<object>` to load different controls into the DataContext.